# Word combination with “eternally”

Tags: word-choice, phrases, phrase-requests

I am currently thinking of engraving text for our wedding rings. Idea is to engrave some nice combination of two words (one word per ring) in order to get phrase close to “forever together”.

I do like word *eternity*, so one combination that I could think of is *eternally together*.

Is that word combination "sound" and correct in terms of usage?

Maybe there is another option close in meaning?

Comment: Life sentence??

Comment: @Poncho1234 that's too cynical..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can I suggest "united", so the whole phrase would be "eternally united"?

Comment: That sounds just perfect, I didn't really liked together in that context. Thank you.